# Why is printf working in Dev C++, but not CLion?

Tags: c++, printf, clion

I've recently started looking for a new IDE to use for C++. I used to use Dev C++, but it's a little barebones in comparison to some of the other IDEs out there.

I've run into an issue, which I tried to talk to my professor about, and he said that it's most likely due to the standard library implementation and not the IDE itself-- which makes me think that I can fix it? I'll get to the point:

In Dev C++, when I say printf ("%'14.2f", variable), it prints as I'd expect it to. But, in CLion, it marks the % symbol and says "Unknown, incomplete or optional format specifier" and prints '14.2f instead of my variable. I know that this is because of the apostrophe, but I don't know how to fix it.

Does anyone have any ideas? My professor said GCC's libstd++ should work fine, but I don't know what to do with that information...

Thanks!

Edit: I'm on Windows, by the way.

Comment: What does the ' in the format string? It's C++, use std::cout!

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf): _If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined_. Hence, any output, generated by such `printf` statement is "correct" - regardless of your expectations.

Comment: Um... Remove the apostrophe? It's invalid in printf format specifiers. Why is it there in the first place?

Comment: We were told to use printf-- with the apostrophe in particular. It adds commas into numbers. (So instead of 1000.00, it shows up as 1,000.00).

Also, like I said, this does work on Dev C++!

Comment: [Reference for the `printf` extension](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Comment: @MichaelBurr: It's important to note that `printf` is provided by the runtime library, not by the compiler. MinGW in particular uses gcc as its C compiler, but can use different implementations of `printf` depending on how it's configured.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the apostrophe as a flag character in a `printf` format string is an extension defined by POSIX:

> The integer portion of the result of a decimal conversion (`%i`, `%d`,
>   `%u`, `%f`, `%F`, `%g`, or `%G`) shall be formatted with thousands' grouping
>   characters. For other conversions the behavior is undefined. The
>   non-monetary grouping character is used.

Your professor is correct: support for this extension is determined by the standard library implementation, not by the IDE or by the compiler.

But:

> My professor said GCC's libstd++ should work fine, but I don't know what to do with that information.

libstdc++ is a C++ library. It doesn't provide the implementation of the `printf` function; that's part of the C library. (The C++ library includes most of the C library.)

You should investigate what C++ implementation (compiler and library) your IDEs are using. You might be able to coax CLion to use the same C++ implementation used by Dev C++.

Comment: " support for this extension is determined by the standard library implementation, not by the IDE or by the compiler." - say what? support for this feature can certainly be determined by the compiler - for example, the GCC compiler does look at format strings, and neither a Standard C nor C++ compiler needs to support this feature

Comment: @NeilButterworth: The gcc compiler does look at format strings, but only so it can issue warnings.After issuing or not issuing a warning, it will just generate a call to the `printf` function with whatever arguments you passed it. Neither gcc nor clang provides an implementation of `printf`. For example, on my system the `printf` implementation is provided by glibc, which is a separate project from gcc.

Comment: @KeithThompson Do you have any idea as to where I should start for doing something like that? I don't have much experience with changing IDEs like this.

Comment: @Andersma: Not really; I don't use an IDE myself. Maybe look in the settings menu?

Comment: I'm getting the same error message from CLion when I try to use the positional arguments, as in `%1$20.16x`